# Master/detail template

Tags: ios, master-detail

I am using the master/detail template and when run in landscape there is only a back arrow on the detail view. I expected a button with the heading of the master view. I assumed that this was the default. What am I missing? How do I add one?

Answer (score 1):

What device are you using to test with? I created a brand new project with master detail and on iPhone 6 simulator in landscape mode I'm seeing this for the detail view of an item I just created:

[image]

That's what you're referring to, right? That your detail view only shows the arrow and not the word "master"?

I'm using Xcode 6.3 with iOS 8.3 SDK.

Maybe provide a screenshot and I may be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using Xcode 6.3 with IOS10.10.3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I'm using Xcode 6.3.2 and IOS 10.10.3. I am starting a new project with the Master/Detail template for the IPAD. If I start the template for an IPhone the "Master" shows up but it does not show when starting the project using the IPAD.